# Execute bat file to print on port with PHP

Tags: php

I would like to print a generated text (in ZPL) with a bat file in PHP on port LPT1.
when I execute the bat file, its works normally but when I try to execute it with PHP nothing happen

in PHP :

```
system("cmd /c C:test.bat");
```

in bat file :
 `copy C:\wamp64\www\labstock\print\eti.txt LPT1
PAUSE`

Result with PHP :

```
C:\wamp64\www\labstock>copy C:\wamp64\www\labstock\print\eti.txt LPT1 0 fichier(s) copi�(s).
```

Result when I execute myself :

```
C:\wamp64\www\labstock>copy C:\wamp64\www\labstock\print\eti.txt LPT1 1 fichier(s) copi�(s).
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to share my printer and put the path in the bat file:

1. Share the printer and give it a name

2.in the bat file ( test.bat ) :

`copy eti.txt "\\PC_NAME\PRINTER_NAME"`

in PHP

```
exec('cmd /c C:[PATH]test.bat');
```

Or to get output :

```
system('cmd /c C:[PATH]\test.bat');
```